# Images not to stretch but still its not loading the full images

Tags: c#, wpf

I was trying to load an image from my file location. The image dimensions are 70*70; it's a thumbnail.

My Image elements are defined in XAML like this:

```
<Image Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Stretch="None" Grid.Row="16" Height="114" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="imgThumbnail"  
       VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="133"  
       Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="2" Margin="28,0,0,0" />
```

In my code behind I used the following:

```
foreach (string filePath in filePathList)
{
   if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath).ToLower().Contains(slugName.ToLower()+"_70x70"))
   {
      if (Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath).ToLower().Contains("_70x70"))
      {
         filePathList_ToBeDeleted.Add(filePath);
         imgThumbnail.Stretch = Stretch.None;
         imgThumbnail.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filePath));
         //image1.Source = filePath.;
      }
   }
}
```

`Stretch.None` seems to be not working in my case; are there any other options I have here to make sure my image is not stretched and get it as it is?

Comment: It's unclear what you want. You say you don't want the image to be stretched, and that it's working in your case. Can you give us a question to answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot guys i figured it out, Two changes looks my picture perfect

Change one in XAML

Height and Width for that image i set it to 70

second change in XAML.CS

Stertch.Uniformfill